# How many finite sequences of real numbers are there?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I have to find the cardinality of the set of all finite sequences of real numbers. 

My solution: 
This cardinality is bounded below by the cardinality of the set of real-valued sequences of length one. There are continuum-many such sequences. Now, we need to find the upper bound. The only thing that I can come up with is this: 
$$|\bigcup _{n \in \mathbb N}\mathbb R ^n| = \aleph_o \cdot \mathfrak{c} = \mathfrak c$$ 
And now I employ the Cantor-Bernstein theorem to conclude that the cardinality in question is the continuum.

Do you think that my solution is correct?

Comment: Yes, I think it's correct.

Comment: no, its not correct as it is stated. You need to show why $\aleph_0\cdot c=c$ or why $|\bigcup\Bbb R^n|=\aleph_0\cdot c$

Comment: It looks just fine... **if** you can justify why do you take that union (which is pretty straightforwards, but still) ...Nice. +1

Comment: @Masacroso I think that is old news at this level...but, of course, the OP should decide.

Comment: @DonAntonio to me this $$|\bigcup _{n \in \mathbb N}\mathbb R ^n| = \aleph_o \cdot \mathfrak{c} = \mathfrak c$$ without more explanation is a chain of symbols, not a proof. Here my "proof" $$abgstyud=jgdgfdt=habavt$$

Comment: The first equality is almost trivial, and the second one is something's that is usually taught before, or at the same time, questions like the present one are asked. Again, it's up to the OP to decide whether he can write that or he must prove that. What you write in your last line is a proof by a kindergarten kid...which, I guess, can be very good for him. What the OP wrote is mathematics.

Comment: @Masacroso 
Do you think that this proof would do? 
$$\aleph_o \cdot \mathfrak{c} = |\mathbb N \times \mathbb R| $$
Bounded below by $$\{0 \} \times \mathbb R$$ and bounded above by $$\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$$ thus $$\aleph_o \cdot \mathfrak{c} = \mathfrak{c}$$

Comment: @Aemilius yes. My prior comments what tried to says is that, if you want to write a proof I think it is good practice to justify, at least a little, each identity. If I want to prove that $A=B$ it is not a proof just write $A=B$, dont you think?